# Condicion para cambiar un estado solo una vez

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De que manera podria establecer que la opcion de estado que elija solamente la pueda cambiar una sola vez,se que para hacerlo es necesario  colocar una condicion debajo del if en el codigo que me defina que solo puedo cambiar el estado de pedido una sola vez y no mas veces, por favor me prodria ayudar con un ejemplo?soy novato hasta el momento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que el estado solo se pueda cambiar una vez, lo más sencillo sería tener un campo en base de datos, que por defecto sea false y cuando hagas un cambio en el estado lo pongas en true. De esa manera si el campo es true, sabes que el estado ya ha sido modificado y harias que el usuario no pudiera cambiar el estado de nuevo.

Comment: me darias un ejemplo de codigo porfavor?